# What's the usage of three dots (...) in dart List?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my code written like this but it gives an error saying:

> Error: A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Question(
      questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'],
    ),
    ...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)
        .map((answer) {
      return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
    }).toList()
  ],
)
```

Comment: Please explain issue before down voting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out my issue. My flutter SDK wasn't upgraded. Ran `flutter doctor` command and sorted out the missing updates. And the syntax seems to be working fine now.

`flutter upgrade`

Dart version (required) >= 2.3

Restart IDE (if the problem persists)

Answer (score 31):

**Dart 2.3 introduce Spread operator (…)**

Reference link : https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d

```
    var a = [0,1,2,3,4];
    var b = [6,7,8,9];
    var c = [...a,5,...b];

    print(c);  // prints: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: post your all code here, let me look into this, may be you are doing wrong you are adding normal list, you have to first add that list into list widget and then try with it.

Comment: @Farwa - as it said in error message - you are trying to put list of items where has to be `Widget`

Comment: Everything was fine but my Flutter SDK was too old. @AndreyTurkovsky

Answer (score 16):

Dart 2.3 comes with the `spread operator (...)` and the `null-aware spread operator (...?)`, which allows us to add multiple elements in Collections.

```
  List<String> values1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  List<String> values2 = ['four', 'five', 'six'];
  var output = [...values1,...values2];
  print(output); // [one, two, three, four, five, six]
```

---

For Flutter, we can use this inside column

```
   Column(
          children: [
            ...values.map((value) {
              return Text(value);
            }),
          ],
        ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 13):

```
var x = [20,30,40];
var list = [1,2,3,x];

// Using the spread operator, adds the items individually not as a list
var separatedList = [1,2,3,...x];

print(list); // length = 4
print(separatedList); // length = 6
```

Results

```
[1, 2, 3, [20, 30, 40]]
[1, 2, 3, 20, 30, 40]
```